# Is it possible to get the xpath via link text?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I would like to be able to locate an element by link text and then pull its xpath into a variable. The reason for this is so that I can them modify the xpath to click a different element within the same table as the first.

What I have is a table that has rows added to it and I have no way of knowing how many rows have been added between tests.

What would be ideal is some way finding an element by link text then extracting the xpath for that element and as I know which column that element is in I can adjust the xpath and click the checkbox.

e.g. if the link text element has an xpath of

```
//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input
```

I know the checkbox will be

```
//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div
```

What I actually need to identify is which //div[?] the element is in when locating by link text.

the table follows the html structure of

```
<div class="tableRow">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td/>
          <td/>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: After a bit more digging around the html it appears that each row is actually a different table inside a different div. What I need to find out is which div the linktext element is in

Comment: maybe, you show a fragment of the structure of your html

Comment: why is this not solution? `//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input[.=22]/../../../td[4]/div`

Comment: can you provide an example within your html structure, what you would like to find as link text and then which element you want to retrieve because of that

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[//input[text()='text to find']]
```

Find a div with input which equals a text

```
//div[//input[@href='http://localhost/']]
```

Find a div with input with link which equals a link provided

If you find all elements and put it into collection, then with indexOf (or similar logic) you can find an index of row.